# Entity Framework giving error : Invalid object name dbo.QaItemTimePoint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, breeze

I have a table in database called `QaItemTimePoint`.

The model class looks like below:

```
[Table("QaItemTimePoint")]
public class QaItemTimePoint
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TimePoint { get; set; }
}
```

When the controller method is executed, I am getting the error:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IQueryable<QaItemTimePoint> QaItemTimePoints()
 {
   return Repository.QaItemTimePoints;
 }
```

The method in the Repository class

```
public DbQuery<QaItemTimePoint> QaItemTimePoints
{
   get { return (DbQuery<QaItemTimePoint>)Context.QaItemTimePoints; }
}
```

Looking at the other posts for the same error, the solutions given do not work for me.

The `DbContext` class contains the `OnModelCreating` method with statement

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

I have also tried adding the schema parameter for the Table attribute in the model class. The strange thing is I do not get any error when I try to execute the method using breeze query from the UI.

Comment: What's the problem? What line of code triggers the exception?

Comment: Is the table created under the default dbo schema?

Comment: @B-Lat Yes, the table is created under dbo schema.

Comment: @KeithPayne When the controller method is executed containing the line Repository.QaItemTimePoints

Comment: Can you maybe post the code where the line Repository.QaItemTimePoints is? Are you specifying the dbo schema somewhere in code? EF is looking for a table/domain object called dbo but it's difficult to diagnose with the code that you have posted.

Comment: @B-Lat I have added the controller method and the repository method. There is no mention of the schema dbo in the code. When I try to execute the controller method from the UI using breeze query, there is no error at all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with breeze. I see you have changed the title of your question to Invalid object name dbo.QaItemTimePoint. That negates what I said previously, because I can see now that it's not looking for the object dbo, it's looking for dbo.QaItemTimePoint. You mentioned pluralisation, is the table in the DB pluralised or not?

Comment: @B-Lat No, the table in db is not pluralised. Its name is same as that of model class name which is QaItemTimePoint

Comment: There's still some missing information in the question. What is calling the controller method? What is the `Type` of the exception?

Comment: @KeithPayne The exception is [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException]. I get this exception when I am trying to execute a call to Repository.QaItemTimePoints within another method from controller.